# How to get the combined result summary in master slave architecture using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have configured two slaves and one master machine.

After executing the performance test in Jmeter using the master slave architecture on master machine, I am getting the result log in slaves machines but I need a consolidated log summary. Please suggest me how can I get it?

Also, I need to know that how the load is distributed over the slave machines.

Answer (score 1):

First question:

If you are talking about the logs (as in jmeter-server.log) there's no automatic way to collect them all. You could write a bash script or something similar to collect them from the servers.

Second question:

Every slave machine executes the full test plan completely on their own. That means that if you configure your test plan to include 10 threads, every slave will run with 10 threads giving you a total of 20.